# I want to get AsyncTask outside. in Task data

Tags: java, android

My code is:

```
public String search ="hello";

public void WeatherSearch() {
    new GeneralAPI(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String result) {
            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONObject cord = null;

                cord = jObj.getJSONObject("coord");
                JSONObject main = jObj.getJSONObject("main");

                main.getString("temp");

                JSONArray weathers = jObj.getJSONArray("weather");
                JSONObject weather = weathers.getJSONObject(0);

                String icon = weather.getString("icon");

                search = weather.getString("description");
                System.out.println(search);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=37.276101&lon=127.130824&APPID=52411ebbc405b9763828164dda220d19");
    System.out.println(" ㅇㅇ " +search);
}
```

Only search print, in search -> clear sky etc...
but ㅇㅇ + search print -> hello ...

But I want to get clear sky data.

I'm trying to `execute().get()` but result is same.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your json:

```
"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}]
```

weather has no property descriptiion, the object inside the list has it, so, you have to take the firs element of the `weather` json object, and then do `.getString("description")`.

```
weathers.getJSONObject(0); is wrong, because it takes an String:
```

> getJSONObject(String name) Returns the value mapped by name if it
>   exists and is a JSONObject, or throws otherwise.

[Documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject%28java.lang.String%29)

In resume, you have to take the first value of the list, and then get the atribute `description`

> resume

You should do:

```
JSONObject weather = weathers.getJSONObject(FIRST_ELEMENT);
```

and not do:

```
JSONObject weather = weathers.getJSONObject(0);
```

Comment: so. what should i do ...?.?
but this code is studied in my university class..
just i want to get to data...

Comment: I updated the answer so you can do the right thing json.getJSONObject(FIRST_ELEMENT). Don't forget accept the anwer if it was useful :)